# Shards are showings as one

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search. I have installed elastic search in my local machine. when I add any document, the result shards total is 2, when I see all indices through _cat API primary and replica are showing as 1 only. But by default shards should be 5, but its showing only 1 for me. for every index default shards are 1 only, I didn't changed any configuration.

Comment: What Elasticsearch version do you use?

Comment: elastic search version  7.3.2

Answer (score 1):

So starting with Elasticsearch version 7.0 the default number of shards was reduced from 5 to 1.

You can see the difference by comparing the [version 6.8](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-create-index.html) and [version 7.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/indices-create-index.html) of the documentation.

If you still want to have 5 shards created for your index, you have to create it like the following:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  }
}
```

The resulting shards after indexing a document is two because you have also one replica. Since you operate a single-node-cluster the replica shard can not be allocated onto another node and therefore only one shard succeeded.

Comment: got it but after adding document, result is _shards {total:2,success:1}, why it is showing total 2 when my shard count is one

Comment: Because of your one replica shard. And since you operate a single-node-cluster the replica can not be allocated onto another node. So this is why you see **success:1**

Comment: You're welcome! I updated my answer. I would really appreciate an acceptance of my answer if you feel satisfied with it :-)